# Android UI vs J2ME UI

Tags: android, java-me, user-interface, mobile

I know Android is better than J2ME, but I need to know what can I do with android but j2me can't? (just about UI), some examples could be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With android, you can create widgets, you have tools for browsing the web amongst many things.

You also have regular expressions (this is a big one), bluetooth, database access, 2D graphics and OpenGL, support for gestures..

Besides, its api is much closer to the Java SE api; which means that you have a wide range of possibilities.

Android development will be much much more interesting than Java ME (j2me).

Comment: Check this link for samples:
http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/index.html

Comment: thx, the widgets idea is great.

i know android has more possibilities, but i would like to know examples of this possibilities.

i have a j2me application, and i have to make it on android but improving it using UI functionality that j2me doesnt have, so i need to know this possibilities or where i can find it, i have searched on the internet but nothing....

Answer (score 2):

J2ME was designed at a time of extremely limited devices (QVGA at best, B&W/grayscale at worst), and some of those decisions shine through in the relatively limited default widgets.  The default widgets in Android are much better.

But imo, this is very secondary to the fact that J2ME is a federation of standards, whereas Android is a more modern, complete, cohesive framework.  J2ME gets its power from a large collection of JSRs with different docs and different release schedules.  OTOH, other than optional features (location based services, etc), Android devices tend to be much more consistent.  Also, I've seen tons of bugs w/ specific J2ME implementations (especially in the location APIs, but I'm sure there are other places as well) that just aren't an issue in Android.